# Content script matching top-level domains like all google.*

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, match, content-script

I want my content script to match all google domains, and a specific page. I know this is not possible.

Manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
           ,"*://www.google.*"
           ,"*://www.youtube.com/*"
           ,"*://readthedocs.org/*"]
       ,
       ....
```

Is there another way to do this? Just wanted to make sure before I list all domains Google has :)

Answer (score 13):

Listing all Google domains is not that difficult, because Google has published a list of all public Google domains at http://www.google.com/supported_domains. Prefix every item in this list with `"*://*` and add the `",` suffix to every item. Then copy-paste the result to your manifest file.

An alternative option is to use the [`"include_globs"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs) field (this is applied after "matches"):

```
{
    ....
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
        "include_globs": [
            "*://*.google.*/*",
            "*://*.youtube.com/*",
            "*://readthedocs.org/*"
        ],
        "js": [ "contentscript.js" ]
    }]
}
```

(I've replaced `"*://www.google.com/*"` with `"*://*.google.com/*`, because of subdomains like https://encrypted.google.com/)

Comment: The list you linked is actually incomplete. It doesn't have [google.ng](http://google.ng) in it

Comment: @Olumide Interesting. Another way to go find Google domains is to look browse the Certificate Transparency logs, e.g. at https://crt.sh/?Identity=google.%25. This list does include google.ng. It also includes many non-Google domains that starts with google.*, but you could compare the list from my answer with the logs, look for missing entries and manually check / verify the unknown entries.

Comment: thanks for the link. Another way to verify is to filter out those certificates that aren't issued by google https://crt.sh/?Identity=google.%25&iCAID=1348