# Matching Github and GHE with Webextensions Match Patterns

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to write an extension that only runs on `*://github.com/notifications` or `*://github.*.com/notifications` (to cover Github Enterprise URLs). Unfortunately the second match pattern is one of the invalid match patterns in [the firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/match_patterns) and [the google docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns), see picture:

[image: Invalid match patterns]

This presumably means I'd have to use `*://*/notifications` instead, and then filter it in the app, which seems like a pain, as it means I have to use a wider scope than I'd need to.

So my question is, is there an easy way to match these urls that I'm missing? Is there a reason that this match is disallowed?

App is [here](https://github.com/gibfahn/gnt) in case that helps.

Comment: Use [include_globs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18616735).

Comment: Such matches are disallowed for security reasons. The matches you list could match almost any domain.

Comment: But you can match `"*://*/*"`, which matches any domain.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, fixed it with the `include_globs` option as suggested in the comment

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "include_globs": [
        "*://*github*notifications*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "browser-polyfill.js",
        "button.js"
      ]
    }
]
```

Still seems odd that you are forced to do this more general match and then filter down with `include_globs`, but maybe this makes it clear that you're actually matching any domain.