# How to match the same domain with multiple extensions in Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

So, I am working on a Chrome extension that needs to be activated on any site with the domain `example.extension` where `extension` can be anything(`.com`, `.de` etc.).

I have a content script and in the `manifest.json` I included all the domain names listed one after another:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*","https://www.example.de/*"]
  }]
```

But how could I write something that matches `example.*` instead of enumerating all of them? 
Note that I tried something like this and it does not work:

```
 "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www.example*"]
  }]
```

Comment: You can use include_globs in the manifest, see the documentation and [Chrome extension: Run on all google domains and a specific page](//stackoverflow.com/q/18613731)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are 2 options:

**First option:**
You make use of the `include_globs` in the manifest as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613731/chrome-extension-run-on-all-google-domains-and-a-specific-page)

```
    "content_scripts": [{
           "js": ["content.js"],
            "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
            "include_globs": [
                "*://*.example.*/*",
            ]
        }]
```

**2nd Option:** You can change your content script to check if the target `URL` matches `www.example.*`:

```
if (window.location.host.startsWith('www.example')){
   //content script code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a persistent background script and inject the script when the url matches your requirement. For example:

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.url.indexOf('https://www.example.') == 0){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{file:'content.js'});
    }
});
```

Comment: @Csaba the comment by wOxxOm in your question might be even better.