# How to make chrome extension work on all domain zones of specific site?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a tiny chrome extension that works on google translate **com**
How can I make it working on all domain zones(not only .com)?

Tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.
`"matches": [ "*://translate.google.*/*" ],`

```
Error
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid host wildcard.
```

---

This is not a duplicate of [Chrome extension: Run on all google domains and a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613731)
I want it to work only on translate page.

```
  "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
  "include_globs": [
    "*://translate.google.*/*"
  ]
```

This part makes it working on google.com search page.
I don't need this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension: Run on all google domains and a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613731/chrome-extension-run-on-all-google-domains-and-a-specific-page)

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried that. But I don't want it to work on pages other that `translate.google` You didn't read that answer at all.

Comment: so you think its ok to set all that list items in extension manually? https://crt.sh/?Identity=google.%25&iCAID=1348 It doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to convert it into a list of entries for "matches" as explained in the answer I've linked (it also has [a list of the TLDs](http://www.google.com/supported_domains) used by Google). Alternatively, you can write a trivial converter or an IDE macro (maybe there is an existing one somewhere). There are no other solutions for manifest.json except those listed in the linked answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Can be closed, I guess. Should I delete it?

Comment: I don't know. Might be still useful if you post your result and a link to that answer for "more info".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @wOxxOm

1. Go to http://www.google.com/supported_domains
2. Open console and paste the following:

```
copy(document.body.innerText.split(" ").map((item) => { return `*://translate${item}/*` }))
```

3. Go to your manifest file and replace `matches": []` array with what you've just copied.