# Chrome URL match patterns (specific depth, varying subdomain and top level domain)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to match url at a specific depth (within folder)
`<>://somewhere.else/folder/<>`

I tried
`*://somewhere.else/*/*`
but it would also match for
`<>://somewhere.else/folder/`

---

I would also like to match url with varying subdomains and top-level domain
`<>://<>.somewhere.<>/<>`
I tried
`*://*.somewhere.*/*`
but it just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> match url at a specific depth

Match patterns can't do it so you'll have to use a broader pattern and check `location.href` in your content script (or in the background script if this is a webRequest event listener).

> match url with varying subdomains and top-level domain

You can use [include_globs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#matchAndGlob) if this is for `content_scripts` in manifest.json: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18616735).

P.S. There are some `chrome` APIs that accept RE2 regular expressions for match patterns (e.g. [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) or [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeNetRequest)) which you can use in the background script.