# How to check current URL Chrome Extension and JS

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to detect the current website and have an if statement to `.test()` it with the desired URL. Right now, inside of my background.js, I have

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(tab => {
chrome.tabs.get(tab.tabId, current_tab_info => {
        if (/^https:\/\/www\.amazon/.test(current_tab_info.url)) {
            chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: 'myStyles.css'})
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'foreground.js'}, () => console.log("Get hacked lol"))
        }
    })
});
```

This works, but only when I switch to another tab and back. So I was wondering how I could keep checking the URL instead of only checking it when I switch tabs.

Comment: Which API event are you using? If it's tabs.onUpdated then it already provides this information inside the third parameter `tab`. Also note, maybe you don't need the background script as you can declare the [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for amazon [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18616735).

Comment: Seeing the updated question, you use tabs.onActivated but it doesn't seem like the right choice because "activated" means "the user has just switched from another tab to this one". Either consider declaring a content script as suggested above or switch to using tabs.onUpdated.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, I tried it out and it works out great! There's only one problem though, every time I hit refresh the function is executed multiple times, is there a way to fix this, or is this not able to be fixed because the website is being loaded multiple times?

Comment: If you use onUpdated then you should check `changeInfo.url`, not `tab.url`