# Run Chrome extension on every domain except one?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need a Chrome extension to run on every domain except for one. It runs everywhere with this:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

However adding `exclude_matches` seems to have no effect:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "exclude_matches": ["http://*.mysite.com/"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

I tried using a match pattern from these docs but the extension still loads on that page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "exclude_matches": ["*://mozilla.org/"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

In the official docs the example is for excluding specific pages for a domain, so maybe it can't be used in the way that I'm trying?

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.nytimes.com/*"],
      "exclude_matches": ["*://*/*business*"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Your first try used `http` so no wonder it didn't work as most sites are https now. In the second try to exclude the parent domain with any sub-domains prefix it with `*.` and add `*` suffix to match any path like `*://*.mozilla.org/*` (it's shown in MDN btw) and there's also `exclude_globs` for more flexibility.

Comment: If I wanted to exclude all TLDs for a domain eg google.org, google.com, google.anything, etc is chrome.webRequest required?  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/

Comment: See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18616735).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run everywhere except "google" domains use `exclude_globs`. In `manifest.json`:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "exclude_globs": ["*://*.google.*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
```